# Call compinit manually in zsh as part of a bindkey function

Tags: linux, zsh

So, I have setup my `.zshrc` to have a basic level of syntax checking by creating `bindkey` lines for basically all character generating keys and pointing them to respective functions that both generate the character and then call the syntax checker.

It is otherwise working perfectly, however I want to apply it to tab so that it will take into account `$BUFFER` changes from `compinit`, however calling `compinit` manually within the `trap_tab` function I created doesn't even call `compinit`.

Any help is much appreciated!

Below is the relevant bit. Just uncomment and recomment the `bindkey` and `zle -N` lines. When uncommented, even though `compinit` is called, I do not receive any autofill options when hitting tab.

```
# Setup basic config stuff for history size, Vim keybindings, and the like
HISTFILE=~/.histfile
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=1000
setopt  extendedglob notify
unsetopt nomatch

# Auto-completion (double-tab tab)
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/terminus/.zshrc'
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select

function trap_tab
{
    compinit
}

#bindkey '  ' trap_tab
#zle -N trap_tab

export EDITOR='vim
```

Comment: Can you please reduce your question to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @MarlonRichert I've edited the original post.

Comment: How is this doing syntax checking? And why would you want to repeatedly call `compinit`?

Comment: @MarlonRichert You asked for a minimal reproducible example, so I did just that. The syntax checking is related, but not a explicit prerequisite of the desire to trap tab while also leveraging the autocomplete function. As for why I repeatedly call `compinit`, it's because as I understand it, that's what does the autocomplete, hence why I manually called it in my function.

Comment: You should call `compinit` only once, on startup. As the name implies, it _initializes_ the completion system.

Comment: And still: How would this accomplish syntax checking?

Comment: @MarlonRichert Again, it doesn't. The problem however, is that without being able to manually call (or more accurately, trap) the zsh completion, I can't subsequently call my syntax checker. Thus, if I can manually call the completion algorithm, I can trap it and make sure my syntax checker is called immediately afterwards.

Comment: You don't need the completion system for that at all. You're asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is no "proper" solution, however at least one guy on GitHub figured out a self-described "hacky" solution which does appear to do what I want, albeit with some additional formatting needed: [github.com/Valodim/zsh-capture-completion](https://github.com/Valodim/zsh-capture-completion)